# What kind of profiler does v8 crankshaft use?

Tags: node.js, v8

I've been reading [1] and it says that crankshaft has 4 major components. The second major component is the crankshaft profiler:

> A runtime profiler which monitors the running system and identifies hot code, i.e., code that we spend a significant amount of the time running.

What I wanted to know is whether crankshaft uses a profiler on a periodic sampling ( like vtune or perf ) or does the compiler generate code for detailed ( or complete ) profiling data. I wanted to ask this because, statistically, this approach does show you hotspots, but only after having collected large amounts of data.

[1] http://blog.chromium.org/2010/12/new-crankshaft-for-v8.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally Crankshaft was using a sampling profiler. These days Crankshaft is using an instrumenting counting profiler with a counter increment inserted at function prologues and loops' back edges.